# Triviality of (equivariant) holomorphic vector bundles

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $G$ the 1-dimensional diagonalisable linear complex analytic group $\mathbb C^*$. We suppose that $G$ acts linearly on $\mathbb C^n$ with positive weights. Set $X=\mathbb C^n -\lbrace 0 \rbrace$. Then every complex $G$-equivariant vector bundle $E$ descends into a complex vector bundle on the (weighted) projective space (or stack) $X/G$.

**Question**:

Fix a  $G$-equivariant complex vector bundle $E$ on $X$. Does there exist a $G$-module $V$ such that $E$ is isomorphic to $X \times V$ as a $G$-equivariant complex vector bundle?

Notes:

1. This question comes from [arXiv:1205.4742](http://arxiv.org/abs/1205.4742). In §4 we use the above statement for a scpecial case where the quotient $X/G$ is $\mathbb P(1,2)$.
2. I initially asked this question with adjective "holomorphic".

Comment: $\mathbb C P^n$ is simply connected but has many nontrivial holomorphic vector bundles.

Comment: Maybe you need to add a (semi)stability assumption for the vector bundle?

Comment: @EricO.Korman I see. Maybe I forgot important conditions and I should concentrate on the second question.

Comment: I'll rewrite my questions to concentrate on the second one.

Comment: $\mathbb C^\times$ is homotopic to $S^1$, which has only trivial complex vector bundles (the space of rank $k$ complex vector bundles over $S^n$ is equivalent to homotopy classes of map $S^{n-1} \to GL(k,\mathbb C)$.  So in this case you get maps $S^0 \to GL(k,\mathbb C)$ and there is just one homotopy class since $GL(k,\mathbb C)$ is path-connected).  So topologically, $E \simeq X\times V$ with $V$ a $G$-module.  However, I think there can be non-trivial holomorphic structures on a trivial bundle over $\mathbb C^\times$.  I'm not sure about this though.

Comment: @EricO.Korman thanks for your comment. I dropped the holomorphic conditions from my question after reading your comment. Could you explain details of your conclusion. (In particular I can not understand why the dimension of $S^n$ decreases when considering homotopy classes. I do not also understand how you deal with the structure of $G$-action.)

Comment: @H.Shindoh For the result on complex vector bundles over spheres, you can see p. 22 of Hatcher's *Vector Bundles and K-theory* available here: http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/VBKT/VBpage.html.  Actually I guess the action of $G$ on $X \times V$ doesn't have to come from a single action of $G$ on $V$, presumably it could vary with $X$.

Comment: @EricO.Korman thank you very much. I understand the (non-equivariant) triviality. I'll think for a while whether every equivariant vector bundle comes from a single $G$-module or not.

Comment: Only concerning holomorphic bundles: given a holomorphic vector bundle $E$ over $\mathbb{CP}^n$, we obtain a $\mathbb{C}^{*}$-equivariant bundle over $\mathbb{C}^{n+1} \setminus 0$. If the underlying holomorphic bundle is trivial, then it will be equivariantly isomorphic to $X \times V$ for $V$ a representation of $\mathbb{C}^{*}$. But $V$ decomposes into $1$-dimensional representations, and so $E$ will decompose into a sum of line bundles. Since there are vector bundles over projective space that do not admit such a decomposition, the answer to your question is no.

Comment: On the other hand, when $X = \mathbb{C}^2 \setminus 0$, the quotient $X/\mathbb{C}^{*}$ (at least when the weights are coprime) is a weighted projective line. Then Grothendieck's decomposition theorem applies (as proved in a paper by Martens and Thaddeus), and the answer to your question, in this case, is yes.